# Can I used my Admob with new play store account?

Tags: admob, google-play-services

Google was suspend my play store account few day before. now my admob account is free. I was open new play store account. Can i used my old Admob with this new account?. Is google track this or suspend my new account also?

Answer (score 1):

i have got suspended from Google playstore for about 25-30 times with the same admob account

as i talked to my admob account manager before he told me that there isn't any innerconnection between admob department and playstore dept.

so, use the same account without any worries ;)